# Angular.module name by default

Tags: angularjs

When

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
```

Then i get module:

```
angular.module('myApp', []); 
var mod = angular.module('myApp')
mod.controller('MyController',
function ($scope) {})
```

I am interested in how to choose the default module when `<html ng-app>`

Comment: This is a good question. The docs say that the name is optional, but fail to explain how to create the module when no name is given.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988506/angularjs-fail-to-load-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From viewing the AngularJS source code. I can only guess that the default name for a `ng-app` module is either just `app` or `ngApp` or `ng-app`. You'll have to try those three to see which one works.

---

The `ng-app` directive is used to create a module via the HTML. If there is no `np-app` directives defined in the HTML, then you have to assign a module to the DOM using `angular.bootstrap`. Without a module an AgularJS application will not work.

When you exclude the module name from `ng-app` a default module is created. This module allows you to use AngularJS directives in the HTML.

The tutorial has a few examples of just `<html ng-app>` being used. That's because there is a lot you can do with AngularJS without writing any JS code. If you're just going to use built-in directives, then you don't have to define a name.

If you want to make changes to the module (such as adding custom directives) then you should assign it a name.

The default name for a module is not a documented standard, and it could change in the future.

Comment: Yes I want added directives

Answer (score 0):

Just change `myApp` to the name of the module you wish to use.