# Angular JS not working on IE9

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to migrate a webpage to angular JS. Its a simple SPA. It has only the basic components like label, texboxes and dropdowns. I can get the page working on chrome and Firefox. However the perfectly good looking page fails on IE9. In IE9 I cant even get angular JS working. As soon asthe page loads I get following JS errors:

> SCRIPT5007: Object expected  
>   angular.js, line 318 character 12 
>   SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'module'  
>   refernce-module.js, line 6 character 1
>   SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'controller': object is null or undefined 
>   refernce-module-controller.js, line 6 character 1

I want to mention that I havent used any angular JS in html except for ng-app(in html tag) and ng-controller (in bodytag).

Following is the controller js code :

```
referenceDataMaintainenceApp.controller('referenceDataMaintainenceCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.lookup_codes = [
    {'key':'FS_ASSET_CLASS','value':'ASSET CLASS - FS'},
    {'key':'account_actc','value':'Non ASSET CLASS - FS'},
    {'key':'account_fee_type_cd','value':'Account Fee Types'}
];




$scope.change_lookup = function() {
   // console.log(new Date('2014-05-02').getTime());
    var key = $scope.lookup_codes_model.key;
    if(key == 'FS_ASSET_CLASS') {
        $scope.lookup_codes_details = [{'name':'ASSET CLASS','description':'Testing the code lookup module for ASSET CLASS.', 'active':true}];
    } else {
        $scope.lookup_codes_details = [];
    }
};


$scope.addLookupCode = function() {

    $scope.lookup_codes_details.push($scope.new_lookup_code);
    $scope.new_lookup_code = getLookupCodeObject();


};

/*----------------------benchmark-----------------------------*/      

$scope.benchmarks_details = [{'name':'Bench 1','description':'BenchMark 1', isNew : false},
                             {'name':'Bench 2','description':'BenchMark 2', isNew : false}];

$scope.addBenchMark = function() {

    $scope.benchmarks_details.push($scope.new_benchmark);
    $scope.new_benchmark = getBenchMarkObject();

  };




  /*----------------------holidays-----------------------------*/    

$scope.calendar_countries = [
                            {'key':'AUST','value':'AUSTRALIA'},
                            {'key':'CANADA','value':'CANADA'},
                            {'key':'CHINUK','value':'CHINA UK'}
                           ];
$scope.calendar_years = [
                            {'key':'2012','value':'2012'},
                            {'key':'2013','value':'2013'},
                            {'key':'2014','value':'2014'}
                        ];

$scope.change_holiday = function() {
    var calendar = $scope.calendar_countries_model;
    var year     = $scope.calendar_years_model;
    if(angular.isUndefined(calendar) || 
            angular.isUndefined(year))
        return;
    else {
        if(calendar.key == 'AUST' && 
                year.key == '2014') {
            $scope.calendar_details = [{'date':'1388620800000','description':'New Year', isdelete : false},
                                         {'date':'1398988800000','description':'May Day', isdelete : false}];
        }
        else {
            $scope.calendar_details = [];
        }
    }
    //console.log($scope.calendar_years_model);

};


$scope.addHoliday = function() {

    $scope.calendar_details.push($scope.new_holiday);
    $scope.new_holiday = getHolidayObject();


};


/*----------------------User Defined PAM Fields-----------------------------*/    

$scope.data_types = [
                            {'key':'date','value':'Date'},
                            {'key':'float','value':'Float'},
                            {'key':'int','value':'Integer'}
                           ];
$scope.pam_screens = [
                            {'key':'account_select','value':'Account Details'},
                            {'key':'fund_select','value':'Fund Detail'}
                      ];

$scope.pams_fields = [{'name':'Benchmark Tolerance','label':'Benchmark Tolerance', 'type':'Date', 'screen': 'fund_select','active':true}];

$scope.addUsedDefPAMFields = function() {

    $scope.pams_fields.push($scope.new_pam_field);
    $scope.new_pam_field = getUserDefinedPamFieldsObject();


};

/*----------------------Broker Code Maintainence-----------------------------*/    


$scope.brokers_details = [{'name':'000200','description':'GREENWICH OPTIONS COMPANY', 'active':true},
                          {'name':'000202','description':'WEISS PECK AND GREER LLC', 'active':false}];

$scope.addBrokerCodes = function() {

    $scope.brokers_details.push($scope.new_brokers_detail_list);
    $scope.new_brokers_detail_list = getBrokerCodeObject();


}; 


});

function getLookupCodeObject () {

lookup_code = {
        name :  '', 
        description : '',
        active : false
};

return lookup_code;
}

function getBenchMarkObject () {

benchmark = {
        name :  '', 
        description : '',
        isNew : false
};

return benchmark;
}

function getHolidayObject () {

holiday = {
        date :  '', 
        description : '',
        isdelete : false
};

return holiday;
}

function getUserDefinedPamFieldsObject () {

pam_fields = {
        name :  '', 
        label : '',
        type : '',
        sceen : '',
        active : false
};
return pam_fields;
}

function getBrokerCodeObject () {

broker_code = {
        name :  '', 
        description : '',
        active : false
};
return broker_code;
}
```

and following is the module js code :

```
var referenceDataMaintainenceApp = angular.module('referenceDataMaintainenceApp', [] );
```

Kindly direct me to fix this browser issue.

Thanks

Comment: What is the version number of your angularjs lib?

Comment: @ Tyler.z.yang : It is v1.3.6

Comment: you should try using a version 1.2.x,m because since version 1.3 IE8 is not supported anymore so it may have some consequencies for IE9, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: could you also try to run your code in a jsfiddle in IE9, and give us a link if it still fails ? or a simpler version ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see the HTML code of where you are including angular.js, refernce-module.js and refernce-module-conroller.js. Because out of the error messages I guess that the angular keyword is not recognized properly and therefore .module, the referenceDataMaintainenceApp assignment and the .controller wont work.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988506/angularjs-fail-to-load-module) this thread may help.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like some of ECMA5 functionalities are not working in IE9. I have been porting AngularJS apps in IE8 to test its compatibility, and you can also try the following tips which helped me out :

1. [ES5 Shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) and [ES5 Sham](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim#shams) (needed for Object.Create polyfill)
2. [JSON3](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/) polyfill for JSON handling
3. Use Angular 1.2.x, which works seamlessly till IE8
4. Use jQuery 1.x.x
5. Always include jQuery **before** AngularJS, as Angular has own jQueryLite which it tends to use, which may cause an error in old browsers

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

This problem occurs because some parts of the AngularJS code are not originally compatible with IE9. I had the same problem and all you need to do is to import [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) in your app **before** AngularJS, as following:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="lib/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/es5-shim/es5-sham.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```